# How to expand TextField in Container vertically to cover all available space in Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-layout, expand

I want to expand a `TextField` to cover all the space vertically, its `Container` is expanding but `TextField` doesn't, here is design:

Blue is the `Container` area. but `TextField` is not expanding

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Title"),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
            child: TextField(
              controller: c_title,
              decoration: Styles.getInputFieldStyle(""),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
            child: Text("Feedback"),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: Styles.getInputFieldStyle(""),
                controller: c_feedback,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: (){_onSubmitPressed();},
              child: Text("Submit"),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: MyColors.theme_red,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 9):

With Flutter 1.5.4 you can do simply the following:

```
Expanded(
  child: TextField(
    expands: true,
    maxLines: null,
  ),
)
```

It will occupy all vertical free space.

Answer (score 3):

You need this.

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter your very long text here"),
  maxLines: double.maxFinite.floor(), 
),
```

Edit: This is the final solution for you.

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text("Title"),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
        child: TextField(
          controller: c_title,
          decoration: Styles.getInputFieldStyle(""),
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
        child: Text("Feedback"),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (_, __) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: Styles.getInputFieldStyle(""),
                controller: c_feedback,
                maxLines: double.maxFinite.floor(),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _onSubmitPressed();
          },
          child: Text("Submit"),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          color: MyColors.theme_red,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Its expanding TextField to bottom of the parent regardless of bottom widget, even there is widget below like button

Comment: @Asad, I saw your history and found that you don't accept answers of people, you just take their help and get away.

Comment: This looks so weird, but it works, thanks, fortunately I didn't have a button at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Just set maxLines to null:

```
TextField(
  maxLines: null,               
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code can help you -

Use "maxLines" and "keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline" to expand text fields

```
new Container(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.black),
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                              focusNode: nodeTwo,
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              maxLines: 4,
                              maxLength: 200,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Add Description',
                                 alignLabelWithHint: true ,
                                  hintText: 'Enter Description',
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: 
                                  FontWeight.w300,fontSize: 14.0),
                                  errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your textField widget is Column's children widget and set `expands: true` .

Can set `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top` to vertical align text in the top.